# Keep Footer at the Bottom of the Page w/ Andromeda Theme

Tags: theming

I recently setup a site using the Andromeda theme and love it! However the only issue I have is that when a page doesn't have much content in it the footer does not stick to the bottom of the page. I have tried to implement some of the css answers I have seen on this site with no luck. Does anyone else know how to implement this?

Comment: Which css answers on this site?  Please provide links.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with CSS using

```
position: fixed;
```

On the footer and placing it on the bottom of the screen.